# Use window to execute a formula instead of using eval

Tags: javascript, eval

My code need to execute a forumla (like `Math.pow(1.05, mainObj.smallObj.count)`).

My path is :

```
var path = mainObj.smallObj.count;
```

as you can see.

If needed, my code can split all variable names from this path and put it in an array to have something like :

```
var path = ["mainObj", "smallObj", "count"];
```

Since I don't want to use `eval` (this will cause memory leaks as it will be called many times every seconds), how can I access it from `window`?

Tried things like `window["path"]` or `window.path`.

If it is always unclear, let me know.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: forget to tell that some config are written in JSON, so when we take the formula, it's interpreted as `"Math.pow(1.05, mainObj.smallObj.count)"` so as a string.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: "eval ... will cause memory leaks...." why do you think so?

Comment: It's not clear why you need the path, `Math.pow(1.05, mainObj.smallObj.count)` would work.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `eval` call the compiler, it will be called 10 times/sec (or even more sometimes) so it will cause - I think - a memory leak.

Comment: The formula is interpreted as a string (`"Math.pow(1.05, mainObj.smallObj.count)"`), my bad, forgot to tell it.

Comment: Are you using a buggy JavaScript compiler?

Comment: So according to you I should go for the use of `eval`, don't you think it will cause memory leaks? Even when called multiple times/second?

Comment: using `JSON.parse()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse which parses a string as JSON to better understand please upload this code online

Comment: I think there is something inherently wrong already by the fact that you are dealing with code/logic in a config file. Whether you use `eval` or not it's already a mess.

Comment: It's a bit confusing where the `path` variable is coming from if you're getting the whole `Math.pow...` as a string. I can write code that will interpret `path` without `eval`, but not the `Math.pow(1.05, ...)` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say there are better solutions then `eval`, but it depends how the *forumla* can be structured. It could be *precompiled* using [`new Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) (this is also some kind of *eval*) but allowing it to be called multiple times without the need to recompile for each invocation. If it is done right it should perform better then an `eval`.

You could do something like that:

```
var formula = {
   code : 'Math.pow(1.05, mainObj.smallObj.count)',
   params : ['mainObj']
}

var params = formula.params.slice(0);
params.push('return '+formula.code);

var compiledFormula = Function.apply(window, params);


//now the formula can be called multiple times
var result = compiledFormula({
  smallObj: {
    count: 2
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer is very good, I will try to implement something like you wrote. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `path` part reconciled by recursively using the bracket notation:

```js
window.mainObj = { smallObj: { count: 2 } };
var path = ["mainObj", "smallObj", "count"];
var parse = function (obj, parts) {
  var part = parts.splice(0, 1);
  if (part.length === 0) return obj;
  obj = obj[part[0]];
  return parse(obj, parts);
};
var value = parse(window, path);
alert(value);
```

Basically, `parse` just pulls the first element off the array, uses the bracket notation to get that object, then runs it again with the newly shortened array. Once it's done, it just returns whatever the result of the last run is.

---

That answers the bulk of your question regarding paths. If you're trying to interpret the rest of the string, @t.niese's answer is as good as any other. The real problem is that you're trusting code from an external source to run in the context of your app, which can be a security risk.